# Convertir un método Future<String> a un String

Tags: flutter, dart

Necesito hacer un filtro para una app en flutter. La función de ese filtro es comprobar si el String obtenido es el deseado, y en tal caso mostrar un card. Si no es el deseado, se muestra un Text("Vacío"). El problema es que ignora el filtro y muestra siempre el card.

```
 Future<String> getBenchPress() async {
  FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  String existe = '';
  final document = await db
      .collection("Pecho")
      .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.email.toString())
      .get();

  if (document.exists && document.get("Bench Press") == true) {
    existe = "Bench Press";
  } else {
    existe = "false";
  }
  return existe;
}

comprobar1() {
  if (getBenchPress().toString() == "false") {
    return const Text(
      "Vacío",
      style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.white,
        fontSize: 10,
      ),
    );
  } else {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        card1(),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Que quieres retornar? Quieres retornar el texto y que referente a esto te liste unas card con el texto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getBenchPress().toString()` no te está devolviendo el String que quieres porque no estás esperando que se complete el Future. Te esta devolviendo el string *Instance of '_Future'*

Primero debes esperar que se complete y luego comprobar si es correcto.

```
comprobar1() async {
  String getBenchPressString = await getBenchPress();
  if (getBenchPressString == "false") {
    return const Text(
      "Vacío",
      style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.white,
        fontSize: 10,
      ),
    );
  } else {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        card1(),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Y de la misma forma, cunado llames `comprobar1()` debes hacerlo de manera asíncrona

```
FutureBuilder<String>(
        future: comprobar1,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot){
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
           return snapshot.data;
          }else{
           return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
        }
);
```

Comment: Estoy llamando al método `comprobar1()` desde un Column(), y me salta esto: " type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Widget' ". Por mas que lo intento no encuentro solución

Comment: Utiliza un FutureBuilder

Comment: Ahí edito mi respuesta para que veas como

Comment: Solucionado, un millón de gracias

Answer (score 1):

Creo que ya se lo que buscas hacer, entonces, la forma más fácil sería poniéndole un `await` al momento que llamas a la función para obtener el texto y hacemos un pequeño cambio en el código:

```
Future<Widget> comprobar1() async {
   Widget? widget;
  if (await getBenchPress() == "false") {
    widget = const Text(
      "Vacío",
      style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.white,
        fontSize: 10,
      ),
    );
  } else {
    widget = Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        card1(),
      ],
    );
  }
 return widget!;
}
```

Entiendo que la función de arriba está retornando un Widget, tienes varias formas de hacer este ejercicio, vamos a hacerlo de la forma en la que creo que lo quieres hacer, una vez tengamos el valor deseado, tienes que crear un `FutureBuilder` dentro del Widget donde lo quieras mostrar, como sabemos que lo que queremos retornar es un Widget, haremos lo siguiente:

```
FutureBuilder(
 future: comprobar1(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Widget> snapshot){
   if(snapshot.hasData){
    final widget = snapshot.data;
    return Center(child: widget);
   }
});
```